# как узнать что окно не активно unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, windows

надо что-бы при переключении окна с игрой, открывалось меню.
на просторах интернета нашёл только один гайд, но он был на unity3d.ru, а он вновь не работает

[image: Не работает.пнг]

[> *вот фулл ссылка на нерабочий гайд*](http://unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=26920)